# Sign jwt with hashed password instead of querying a database of blacklisted tokens

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt

I am trying to find out what is the best method for refreshing authentication tokens. I came across someone saying it might be possible to sign the refresh token with the users hashed password when issuing the token. Then if there is an issue with the token being stolen the user can just change their password and all is good again. Is this a valid strategy or is there issues with this.  I could just send the users id stored in a refresh jwt and query the database when refreshing. I know the point of jwt is to be detached from the database but if you need to have some way to blacklist a token you would need to query some kind of database or table anyway. You could just do something like the following:

Sign with users hashed password

```
const { email, password } = req.body
const user = await User.findOne({ email })
if (!user || !user.verified)
  return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Invalid login attempt' })

await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

const accessToken = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET_ACCESS, {
  expiresIn: '5m',
})

const refreshToken = jwt.sign({ id }, user.password + process.env.JWT_SECRET_REFRESH, {
  expiresIn: '1m',
})

res.cookie('accessToken', accessToken, {
  httpOnly: true,
})

res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
  path: '/auth/refresh-tokens',
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 180),
  httpOnly: true,
})
```

Then you can just check the database when you need to refresh the tokens

```
const token = req.cookies.refreshToken
const { id } = jwt.decode(token)
const user = await User.findOne({ id })

jwt.verify(token, user.password + process.env.JWT_SECRET_REFRESH)
```

Is this a valid strategy or is there something wrong doing it this way. It seems like it would be the same stress on the database than trying to find a blacklisted token or storing blacklisted tokens.

Comment: "*but if you need to have some way to blacklist a token*" - then yes, you maybe should not use a token but a simple session storage.

Comment: "*It seems like it would be the same stress on the database than trying to find a blacklisted token or storing blacklisted tokens.*" - the blacklist approach is more efficient since there are much fewer blacklisted tokens than password, and the blacklisted tokens will expire so the list shrinks automatically. But if you store both in a database, yes, it's the same number of requests/stress level (the only difference might be the size of the table kept in cache).